# Creation of temporary files while running queries in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 2GB database running on Linux and monitor query logs through pgbadger. Looking into pgbadger, I can see that there are 372 KiB temporary file size generated during query execution. How can I check those temporary files through terminal in database? Is it normal? what happens if temporary file size grows?

Comment: Please actually show the relevant "database log" entries. Edit the question to include them, then comment here when done.

Comment: Hi Criag, There is no such "database log" in stack overflow.

Comment: You say "looking at the database logs, I can see...". Well. Please *edit the question* to *add that information to your question*.